# by command to find out the maximum number from a list

Tags: r, list, max

I have a list like this :

```
Ll 
$a
3.4 5.6 -2.1 -7.8
$b
2.1 6.7
$c
-6.7,0.001,8.9
```

I want to find out the maximum number for all elements of the list irrespective of the signs.
i.e. I want my out put to look like this :

```
Ll
$a
-7.8
$b
6.7
$c
8.9
```

Is there a way to do this through single command line ?
Can it be done using the 'by' command?

Comment: `by` does operations on subsets that are defined by a categorical variable. I don't see see such a variable in this problem definition. Lists with an iregulat set of lengths would be a particularly unsuitable argument to the `by` function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reproducible code/data always helps:

```
L1 <- list(a = c(3.4, 5.6, -2.1, -7.8), b = c(2.1, 6.7), c = c(-6.7, 0.001, 8.9))
```

Use `lapply` to apply your own function to each element, `which.max` easily finds the maximum, and we just get the `abs`olute value within each:

```
lapply(L1, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
$a
[1] -7.8

$b
[1] 6.7

$c
[1] 8.9
```

Comment: and how can I find the indices of the maximum value?

Comment: return them instead of the value lapply(L1, function(x) which.max(abs(x)))

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` is your friend!

eg.

```
.list <- list( a = 1:5, b = runif(7), c = -3:1)
 lapply(.list, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
## $a
## [1] 5
## 
## $b
## [1] 0.9248526
## 
## $c
## [1] -3
```

Answer (score 1):

which.max will give you index number and value, however if you need just number that you can try this:

max(sapply(yourlist, max))